# Why does the meta tag use name-content pairs and not regular attributes?

Tags: html, metadata

More of a theoretical question, but wouldn't it make more sense to have only one `meta` tag with a bunch of attribute-value pairs? Instead of:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Joe Schmoe, jks@example.com" />
    <meta name="description" content="An article that summarizes the risks 
        and benefits of playing video games for high school students." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="video games, high school students, 
        development, cognition, learning, problem solving, strategy, 
        parenting, time management, procrastination" />
    <title>I'm About to Graduate but I'm Obsessed with Skyrim</title>
    ...
</head>
```

Wouldn't it save some bytes to just write:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" author="Joe Schmoe, jks@example.com" 
        description="The risks and benefits of playing video games 
            for high school students."
        keywords="video games, high school students, development, 
            cognition, learning, problem solving, strategy, 
            parenting, time management, procrastination" />
    <title>I'm About to Graduate but I'm Obsessed with Skyrim</title>
    ...
</head>
```

If the values of the `name` attribute are preset, why not just make them attributes? My method would be easier and smoother for Webpage authors, and I'm sure it would be easy to re-program Website crawlers/robots to understand it. Relevantly, **is there a reason why it can't be done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantages to having the `name=` and `content=` attributes are that you don't have to change the HTML specification each time you need new key-value pair.  Otherwise, you'd have a new version of HTML (which needs to be accepted by the W3C members) each time.

While there a known key-value pairs used by browser, those are not the only pairs you can use to make valid HTML documents, its just that most browser might not used it.  You can also see this in the [HTML 5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#other-metadata-names).  It will list the basic pairs.  And show examples of extension.

By having the key-value approach, the markup is very easily extendable for future version.

Comment: [Actually, you do.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/meta#attr-name). The `<meta />` tag's `name` attribute has a specific set of permitted values. If you need a new key-value pair, the Spec still has to be changed.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-META  ;  Under the name attribute you'll see the words "This specification does not list legal values for this attribute."

Comment: Agreed, but I was thinking more along the lines of [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#standard-metadata-names).

Comment: I already updated my post with references to HTML 5.  It's the same thing.